# matrix multiplication in C++

Tags: c++, performance, eigen

I have the following function that takes too long to execute.

I need to made this at least 2x times faster.

```
 for (size_t i = 0; i < mat1.size(); ++i)
 {
    for (size_t k = 0; k < mat1[0].size(); ++k)
    {
       for (size_t j = 0; j < mat2[0].size(); ++j)
       {
         res[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe, in the question(&code…), the task the code presented is to accomplish.

Comment: It should return the right matrix as output (same values as the first non-optimised code)

Comment: Do not comment comments asking for clarification or complementary information: edit your post. This is not chat. Care to edit the description of tag [tag:eigen]?

Comment: What you mean by right matrix?

Comment: `[not] the same result, I'm doing the right calculation` what is the relative difference? First thing I thought was *going by result, one could accumulate using double arithmetic without increased memory footprint*.

Comment: let me change the title. @convert for right matrix I mean that my current code is giving me the correct output. Optimising it using Eigen gives me wrong output, so I'm not doing it correctly

Comment: @greybeard I don't know what's the difference, but the values of the two output matrix (with Eigen and without Eigen) is different

Comment: Eigen computes the values using at least doubles, you only cast the final result. In the code you present, you "accumulate doubles in a float": *expect* higher inaccuracies.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the title. For the float: yes I expect inaccuracies, but it's really wrong values (different orders of magnitude)

Comment: How do you know which of two disagreeing values is closer to correct?

Comment: The first code gives me the expected output (as that will be used for further analysis and it's correct).
Second code it's just an attempt to optimise and the goal is to have the exact same value as output of the first code.

Comment: While we help optimize code, the fact that you want help with optimization should be in the body of the question rather than the title. To help you optimize the code we need to see more of the code than a single function, if this is in a class it would help if you posted the entire class including the header files at the top. Could you explain what you are using the matrix for in the question? Why are you performing matrix multiplication? Just FYI, there are currently 2 votes to close this question because it doesn't have enough information.

Comment: Thanks for editing; you've probably overdone the reduction.  It's hard to give a review when there's no definition for `size_t`, `mat1`, `mat2` or `res`.  An ideal would be a full function along with any necessary headers, and a `main()` function that demonstrates it produces the correct result.

Comment: Please find [How to get the best value out of Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions).

Comment: don't edit the question once you have an answer especially if it would invalidate the answer, instead post a new question as a followup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you don't need the precision of double then go with single precision floats in the temporary vectors. This can double your performance if the compiler can vectorize it. And you can avoid needing to up-convert to double and then down-convert from double to float right in the innermost of the loop.

   Even adding a `static_cast<float>` in the inner loop shrinks the generated code from 14 math + 3 loop instructions to 10 + 3 when checking on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/G71hTnPo4). But making all inputs single precision makes the inner loop as small as 6 + 3 per loop. (compiler was GCC 12.2 with `-O3 -ffast-math` and I picked the loops which got unrolled to handle 4 elements per iteration).
2. Consider transposing `spectro` and swapping the inner two loops. If you really need the precision of double then you can keep the temp result as a double and only do the conversion to single precision after the loop:

   ```
   for (std::size_t i = 0; i < melBasis.size(); ++i)
   {
       for (std::size_t j = 0; j < spectro.size(); ++j)
       {
           const std::vector<double>& bas = melBasis[i];
           const std::vector<double>& spec = spectro[j];
           double res = 0;
           for (std::size_t k = 0; k < bas.size(); ++k)
           {
               res += bas[k] * spec[k];
           }
           melS[i][j] = res;
       }
   }
   ```

   That way the longest loop (1025 iterations) is the innermost one which means that less time is spent managing the outer loops (this comes out to 4 + 3 instructions in the inner most loop handling 2 elements). However if you make the inputs single precision then it will handle twice the amount of elements per loop.

Note that simply counting instructions isn't the best way to approximate performance as different instructions have different performance characteristics however it is a decent starting point.

---

Your eigen code is wrong because `melBasis[0].data()` will only return a pointer to the first row of data, while eigen expects the pointer to be the full data so it will read out of bounds. You will have to fill those matrices row by row.

Comment: I started from the first snippet you posted I didn't consider the eigen code at all as you indicated it didn't do what you wanted

Comment: You are right, thanks, however this produce crash: MyApplication(74506,0x7000019e2000) malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x7fad91706988: probably modified after being freed.

Comment: You are right! Now it works with Eigen, thanks!
But anyway is still not that fast also with Eigen, and unfortunately, using the code you provided I get the crash above

Comment: keep in mind that the code snippet in the assumes spectro is transposed, and I didn't fully pay attention to make sure I didn't introduce errors, you'll have to double check the logic yourself there

Comment: The question has been closed; if it gets reopened it will likely look quite different and this answer will need extensive revision.  :-(

Comment: I think the inner loop is a good candidate for `std::transform_reduce()` - that's the normal way to write a dot-product.  And it's fine with `std::execution::par_unseq`.